# How to give specific number to the key

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Recently I created an Android application with Firebase as backend. I have read and write options in my application. Every time I upload the data to Firebase an automatic keyname is generated. I want to give a specific number to the keyname, like 1,2,3,4. How is it possible?

Firebase Structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want to do is wrong, don't do it. Firebase is creating this `ID` for you to prevent overwrite these values/objects. If 2 or more ppl will add new record in the same time they may overwrite it. If you still think you should do it, I suggest you to rethink what you do cause it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you **not** to use `1, 2, 3, 4` as keys for your nodes. Using sequential ids for that, is an anti-pattern when it comes to Firebase realtime database, since it will cause for sure scalability problems.

The scalability comes from how Firesbase spreads the data out over its storage layer. So sequential ids have more hashing collisions, which means you hit write limitations sooner. Having ids that are more random ensures the writes are spread out evenly across the storage layer.

If you are interested, [here](https://gist.github.com/mikelehen/3596a30bd69384624c11) you can find the algorithm behinde the `push()` method.

If you are interested to implement your own mechanism, you can take a look at [UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) which can help you generate unique keys for your Firebase database nodes without having to use the `push()` method.

```
import java.util.UUID;

DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userRef = rootRef.child("Users");
//key = userRef.push().getKey();
key = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

This another approach but I strongly recommend you using those pushed ids because are based on time and are generated entirely on the client without consultation with the server.